# What is an idiom for better than "textbook case", "by the book" or "best practices"

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, titles

Something indicating above and beyond the standard best practices, superior to by-the-book-experience.

For instance, I would like to use it in a blog title The non-textbook / non-standard / beyond best practices / virality of XYZ, to indicate that XYZ is doing a better job and not following standard textbook techniques.

The following does not indicate more effective or positive.
"The non-standard approach to organic discovery and viral loops in XYZ"

---

Alternatively, I'd like to say XYZ does not follow the best practices of virality but it doing way better. An idiom, phrase or even a word would work.

Comment: You are not using antonym correctly in your title and in your first sentence.  Why not just say "what is an idiom for better than ...." in the title and delete the first sentence?

Comment: The three idioms in your title do not mean the same thing.  (Nowhere near, in fact.)  It is unclear what it is that you want.

Comment: And how is it possible to be "above and beyond" best practices?

Comment: I used or to separate them.

Comment: "Best practices" is where entrepreneurs start.

Comment: @HotLicks Going "above and beyond best practices" is easy. Choose a method at random from here: https://ig.ft.com/sites/guffipedia/

Comment: It is still unclear what it is that you want.

Comment: *I'd like to say XYZ does not follow the best practices of virality but it doing way better.*  It's possible that XYZ does not follow the *common formula* or adhere to *industry standards*, but there is no way to do "better" than "best practices", by definition.

Comment: @HotLicks Wouldn't say that. _Best practice_ is something seen as “superior to any alternatives because it produces results that are superior to those achieved by other means or because it has become a standard way of doing things” (to quote the Wikipedia article). There's always room for improvement even on best practices—particularly the ones that are just standard ways of doing things.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Look up "best".

Comment: @HotLicks Look up ‘best practice’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'm talking English here, and "best practices" as used in, say, engineering, not marketing-speak.

Comment: @HotLicks I can't speak for engineering specifically (which I would definitely not call more English than marketing speak), but within academia, medicine, publishing, insurance, and just run-of-the-mill enterprising, _best practices_ does not refer to some unchangeable, perfect method of doing things that can never in any way be improved upon. It refers, exactly as every dictionary I've looked up the term in so far, to “procedures that are _accepted or prescribed_ as being correct or most effective”. Best practices change all the time as technology advances and ‘best’ is no longer best.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You're really describing "common practice" or "by the book".

Comment: @HotLicks The way it's used in practice, _best practice_ and _by the book_ are very close to being synonyms, yes, the only difference being that doing something by the book has a bit more wiggle room for laziness. _Common practice_, on the other hand, means something else entirely to me: it's descriptive, rather than prescriptive. In an ideal world, common practice and best practice would be the same, but in the real world, I've only rarely come across places where they are.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Requests to help name something are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to say XYZ does not follow the best practices of virality but it doing way better. An idiom, phrase or even a word would work.

Is anything wrong with saying it's doing it in a **[unorthodox](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unorthodox) yet [superior](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superior)** way?

> Contrary to what is usual, traditional, or accepted
>
> Of high standard or quality

Answer (score 3):

---

**paradigmatic**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/paradigmatic)

> constituting, serving as, or worthy of being a pattern to be imitated

*"XYZ is the **paradigmatic** technique/practice/case for reproducibly solving this problem."*

---

**archetypal/archetypical/archetypic**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetypal)

> 1:  the original pattern or model of which all things of the same type are representations or copies

*"XYZ is the **archetypal** technique/practice/case that sets a model for everyone to use."*

---

**quintessential**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quintessential)

> 2. of or relating to the most perfect embodiment of something

*"XYZ is the **quintessential** technique/practice/case for solving this problem."*

---

Comment: Similar to _paradigmatic_ is ***model***.

Answer (score 2):

MW defines ***[avant-garde](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avant-garde)*** (from French, “advance guard”) as

> an intelligentsia that develops new or experimental concepts
>   especially in the arts

This could plausibly be applied to a person
who develops and field-tests new techniques,
before they get distilled and codified;
or to the techniques themselves.

Related:

- [What do you call a person who started something
  that is later followed by everyone?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/99869/26083)
- [Single word for ‘being one step ahead of others’](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/175575/26083)
- [Synonym for good/productive/star employee](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/314067/26083)
- [What’s a word for someone who pushes boundaries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/289599/26083)
- [What’s a word for “a person who strives to be unique”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/334704/26083)

Answer (score 2):

If I were to say that XYZ approach does better than "best practices," I would say it  ***raises the bar***, or *sets a new standard*.   If you want to use a single word you could call it ***novel***, like the patent office.
The entire concept of *state of the art* admits that the current state is ephemeral and will advance.

> [***novel***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novel) - new and different from what has been known before
>
> [***raise the bar***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raise_the_bar) - To raise standards or expectations, especially by creating something to a higher standard.